# how to change action button color in matsnackbar?

Tags: html, css, angular, types, angular-material

I'm using snackbar in my Angular 9 project but some reason I'm getting the same background and text color for  action button. I added css style in the component.scss file and also global style.scss file but still not working.

```
this._snackBar.open(`Chart has been copied to ${workspace.name}`, 'Check it out!', 
{ duration: 5000, panelClass: "blue-snackbar"}).onAction().subscribe(() => {})

I also tried like this 
panelClass: ['my-snack-bar', 'button-bar']}
```

I also add this in styles.scss and component.scss file but still not working

```
.my-snack-bar {
    background-color: #E8EAF6;
    color: red;
}
.button-bar {
    background-color: pink;
    color: blue;
}
```

example

[image]

Not sure why it's happening..any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your global styles file, usually styles.scss you need to target the panelClass property, something like this:

```
.my-snack-bar {
    background: #2196F3;
    button {background:white; color: blue}
}
```

Here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4-b1fuu5